# email duplicate login with api google in laravel because I have email in database same with google email akun

Tags: php, database, laravel, google-oauth

this is my controller, so i wanna to make this function to handle if email in database null so i can to insert but if email in database already available i can to update so not duplicate

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
    Auth::login($authUser, true);
    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}
```

maybe in where the main must to be change please if you know help me, thanks

```
public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
{

    $authUser = User::where('email', $user->email)->exists();
    if ($authUser) {
        return $authUser;   
    }
    else {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'provider' => strtoupper($provider),
            'provider_id' => $user->id
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try firstOrNew() ?

Comment: thank yao i was solved for this